# Can temporary functions/macros be created in PHP?

Tags: php, function, macros, temporary

Take a look at the following illustration:

```
// Trims input, fixes spaces and encodes bad glyphs. Also works with arrays.
function prepare_param($param)
{
    $retval = "";

    function prc($param)
    {
        $r = split(" ", trim($param));
        foreach($r as $i => $e)
            $r[$i] = urlencode($e);
        return join("+", $r);
    }

    // If input is an array
    if(is_array($param))
    {
        $retval = array();

        foreach($param as $e)
            $retval[] = prc($e);
    }
    // If input is a string
    else if(is_string($param))
    {
        return prc($param);
    }
    else throw new Exception("Invalid input! Expected String or Array.");
}
```

Obviously the function `prc` will now be declared globally, even though declared inside a function. Is there a way to follow this principle, creating a tiny function/macro inside another function as not to litter the global scope? The alternative would be to make a class with a private function, which seems like overkill for my use.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.3, enter anonymous functions:

```
$prc = function($param)
{
    $r = split(" ", trim($param));
    foreach($r as $i => $e)
        $r[$i] = urlencode($e);
    return join("+", $r);
};

if(is_array($param))
{
    $retval = array();

    foreach($param as $e)
        $retval[] = $prc($e);
}
else if(is_string($param))
{
    return $prc($param);
}
```

In this case, `$prc` only lives in the scope of your `prepare_param()` function.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), which are anonymous functions.

Comment: Pedantic note: closures are different from anonymous functions in that closures include scope.  In PHP, all closures are anonymous functions, but not all anonymous functions are closures.  It's only a true closure if you include the `use ($var)` declaration (but PHP's docs and internal representation treat them the same)...

Answer (score 1):

[anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) might be what you are looking for

```
<?php
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
?>
```

If you don't use php 5.3 please be aware of the fact that the memory allocated by the "`create_function()`" function isn't released until the php process finishes. So if you create a lot of functions you might be running into issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to >=PHP 5.3, you can use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), and if not, you can use [create_function](http://php.net/create_function).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have PHP 5.3, you can use the [`create_function`](https://www.php.net/create_function) function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do so. The closures/anonymous functions are possible from PHP 5.3, and the oldschool way would be to use `create_function()` - which is quite fugly.

However in your case, you don't want either. There is no benefit in creating or recreating the function. You just need it once, as it does not depend on any initialization state. The idiom you should use is called "dererred definition" and possible in PHP with:

```
if (!function_exists("prc")) {
    function prc($param) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You should name it with its parent function as prefix however (e.g. `prepare__prc`) to avoid clashes and to signalize its internal use.

Oh, and btw it could also be <s>simplified</s> compacted into:

```
$param = join("+", array_map("urlencode", split(" ", trim($param))));
```